# How do you handle memory management of outlets in the iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, properties, nib

Since KVC is used to set outlets on the iPhone, there are 2 methods (that I know of) to make sure you've properly handled memory management.

Specifically, I am referring to this [article](http://weblog.bignerdranch.com/?p=95) written by Aaron Hillegass.

My question is which method do you use and what is your reasoning?

- Release all your outlets in dealloc
  and viewDidUnload (Make sure you set
  them to nil in viewDidUnload.)
- Make your outlets weak references

Personally, I am leaning towards using weak references as it seems cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I go with weak references.  As you say its less cluttered and makes an already overly verbose code foorprint a little more manageable

Comment: +1 I also use (nonatomic, assign) for all my outlets. Then I don't have to remember to do anything.

Comment: But as the article states, you have to make sure the view is loaded when you use this technique - or you can encounter random crashes accessing IBOutlets after the view unloads.

Answer (score 1):

Weak references are easier, yes.  Clearer?  A retain property as just as clear, and you can be more explicit about when something is released.

Personally I like to primarily use properties to expose some attribute of the class to the outside world - so for IBOutlets only the class will manipulate, I simply declare them without using properties and release them in dealloc.

In either case set to nil IBOutlet references in viewDidUnload.